# C++ SFML doesn't run on Win32

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sfml

I was searched for answers, but can't find them. My problem is that when I try to launch SFML project in Visual Studio 2010 in Win32 it writes me "error LNK2019", but when I am launching it on x64 it's works correctly. How I should be?

Comment: SFML have only 1 type of libs. There is no x64 or x32 libs.

Comment: that is demonstrably not true

Comment: look at this: http://i.imgur.com/3zZ8T2c.png

Comment: Sorry for my stupidnes. Thank you, now it works)